# Taking string within quotation marks in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, quotation-marks

I'm trying to get the content of a string within a string, delimited by double quotation marks ("). My HTML is as following:

```
<body>
  <div>
    sqlString = "UPDATE galleria SET image_description = @image_description WHERE id = " + image.Id;
  </div>
</body>
```

and I'm trying to get the

```
UPDATE galleria SET image_description = @image_description WHERE id =
```

as a single string via my javascript. I know this is probably possible using indexOf or some related method, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on the sqlString variable

```
var lastIndex = sqlString.lastIndexOf("=");
var subString = sqlString.substring(1, lastIndex);
```

subString should contain your required string.

Comment: Yeah. That would work. Do you have any idea if I want to concatanate the string even further? Like with sqlString = "UPDATE " + dbName + " SET "...

Comment: and in such case you want only UPDATE SET as a return string?

Comment: I would want UPDATE as one string and SET as another string.

Comment: You could extract every second value from the array `sqlString.split ('"')`

Answer (score 1):

Give you DIV tag an id attribute, and reference the div by that id.

```
<body>
   <div id="div1">
     sqlString = "UPDATE galleria SET image_description = @image_description WHERE id = " + image.Id;
  </div>
</body>
```

Then match the string using regular expression:

```
var $div = document.getElementById('div1');
var matches = $div.innerHTML.match(/(?!")([^"]+)/g);

if(matches!==null) {
    alert(matches[1]); 
}
```